# Windows 2008 R2 Running Exchange 2010 - ECP and OWA

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, iis-7.5

I am running a trial of Exchange and just set the server up. Email working fine with it, but I cannot access the webpages for the Exchange Control Panel or the OWA website. I get a 500 Error even from trying to open the URL on the server itself.

Comment: Are there any errors in the event logs or IIS logs?

Comment: Is this still an issue or were you able to resolve it?  If resolved, add an answer so the community can learn.

Comment: I was able to fix it by installing Exchange 2010 SP2. It picked up some features that were not turned on in IIS and after enabling those, everything worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange 2010 SP2 installation identified features that were not active in IIS. Once these features were added to IIS, the OWA and ECP pages worked correctly.